# Events not occurring at correct time interval c# timers

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

I am writing a program which sends and recieves messages to another application.
Some messages have to be sent at certain intervals. For example, I have four messages which get sent, one should be sent every 8 seconds, two are to be sent every 0.5 seconds and one should be sent every 1 second.

The messages seem to be sending fine, however they are all sending at the same time. I used a timestamp to determine that they all seem to be sent every 11 seconds. Below is the code I have implimented:

Here are where the timers are declared:

```
    System.Timers.Timer statusTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
    System.Timers.Timer heightTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(500);
    System.Timers.Timer keepAliveTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(8000);
    System.Timers.Timer longHeightTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(500);
```

And here in the main window they are started (this is a WPF project):

```
 statusTimer.Start();
 heightTimer.Start();
 keepAliveTimer.Start();
 longHeightTimer.Start();

  statusTimer.Elapsed += delegate { sendStatusMessage(); };
  heightTimer.Elapsed += delegate { sendHeightMessage(); };
  keepAliveTimer.Elapsed += delegate { sendKeepAliveMessage(); };
  longHeightTimer.Elapsed += delegate { sendLongWarpMessage(); };
```

Here is an example of a method which is should be fired when the time is elapsed (there is not much point in showing them all as they are all basically the same):

```
 public void sendStatusMessage()
    {
        sendMessage(status_msg.TranslateToMessage());
        Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (System.Action)delegate //change the priority so you can use UI
        {
            statusMsgLbl.Content = "Status Msg Sent: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        });

    }
```

And finally this the method which sends the message, as bytes, to the other application using a network stream:

```
 public void sendMessage(byte[] toSend)
    {
        try
        {
            lock (NSLock)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < toSend.Length; i++)
                {
                    nwStream.WriteByte(toSend[i]);
                    nwStream.Flush();
                }
            }
        }
        catch { MessageBox.Show("Unable to send message"); }
    }
```

Comment: As a note, it seems extremely inefficient to write and flush each single byte to a stream, when you could write the entire byte array with a single [`Write(toSend, 0, toSend.Length)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.write(v=vs.110).aspx) call. It may also make sense to use the DispatcherTimer class to avoid the need for calling Dispatcher.Invoke.

Comment: @Clemens thank you for the tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to use a DispatcherTimer with an async Tick event handler:

```
DispatcherTimer statusTimer = new DispatcherTimer
{
    Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)
};

...

statusTimer.Tick += async (s, e) =>
{
    var message = status_msg.TranslateToMessage());

    await nwStream.WriteAsync(message, 0, message.Length);

    statusMsgLbl.Content = "Status Msg Sent: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
};

statusTimer.Start();
```

Comment: this worked perfectly thank you! I haven't seen a timer implimented in this way before, please would you be able to explain the aysnc (s, e) part just so I could grasp a better understanding??

Comment: See [Asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async).

Comment: Thank you! @Clemens

Comment: When writing to the stream doesn't take too much time (e.g. it's only a few bytes to write) it should work as well without async/await. Use `nwStream.Write(...)` instead of `await nwStream.WriteAsync(...)` then.

Answer (score 0):

The date is the same because its the date of code running in `Invoke`, you have to capture date before invoking:

```
public void sendStatusMessage()
{
    sendMessage(status_msg.TranslateToMessage());
    var text =  "Status Msg Sent: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => statusMsgLbl.Content = text);
```

Comment: Would that explain 11 seconds instead of 0.5?

Comment: @Clemens, perhaps combined `TranslateToMessage` for all messages takes that much.

Comment: Hi @Sinatr it still seems to be sending every 11 seconds. When I first tried your code, I accidentally didn't add the top line, so no messages were being sent, and the timer was displaying correctly then which may show the error is somewhere within the send message method and not the timer itself.

Comment: I can't explain why `Invoke` is delayed by 11 seconds and then all of invokes occurs. Perhaps you are blocking UI?